# What is this piece of Python code doing?

Tags: python, math, syntax

This following is a snippet of Python code I found that solves a mathematical problem.  What exactly is it doing?  I wasn't too sure what to Google for.

```
x, y = x + 3 * y, 4 * x + 1 * y
```

Is this a special Python syntax?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
x, y = x + 3 * y, 4 * x + 1 * y
```

is the equivalent of:

```
x = x + 3 * y
y = 4 * x + 1 * y
```

**EXCEPT** that it uses the original values for x and y in both calculations - because the new values for x and y aren't assigned until both calculations are complete.

The generic form is:

```
x,y = a,b
```

where a and b are expressions the values of which get assigned to x and y respectively. You can actually assign any tuple (set of comma-separated values) to any tuple of variables of the same size - for instance,

```
x,y,z = a,b,c
```

would also work, but

```
w,x,y,z = a,b,c
```

would not because the number of values in the right-hand tuple doesn't match the number of variables in the left-hand tuple.

Comment: i think a temporary variable adds clarity. hope you don't mind

Comment: I actually think that explaining it with an emphasized "EXCEPT" drives home the point clearer, so I reverted the change. Thanks anyways for the attempt at improvement, I just happen to be of a different mind on the matter. :)

Comment: Makes perfect sense.  Seeing it wrapped in parentheses made it totally clear.  Very easy to read it fast and miss that little detail.  Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

It's an assignment to a [tuple](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences), also called *sequence unpacking*. Probably it's clearer when you add parenthesis around the tuples:

```
(x, y) = (x + 3 * y, 4 * x + 1 * y)
```

The value `x + 3 * y` is assigned to `x` and the value `4 * x + 1 * y` is assigned to `y`.

It is equivalent to this:

```
x_new = x + 3 * y
y_new = 4 * x + 1 * y
x = x_new
y = y_new
```

Comment: Probably even clearer if you group the parentheses differently: `x, y = (x + 3 * y), (4 * x + 1 * y)`.  The comma can be easy to miss in there.

Comment: Ah, yes, the parentheses made it all clear -- eyes couldn't see it before [slaps forehead]...

Answer (score 0):

I also recently saw this referred to as "simultaneous assignment", which seems to capture the spirit of several of the answers.